# Android App - sharedpreferences not loading properly

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am having issues loading the sharedpreferences. This is my first app with no prior coding experience. The app allows the user to count their number of "Drinks" and "Shots".

The buttons increase their appropriate textView by "1". When I close the app and open it the numbers stay intact and the buttons keep increasing the value by "1".

The problem is When the app is destroyed and opened. The textView's will show the numbers that were left, but when I press a button they rest back to 1. So, the the correct numbers are being loaded, but the buttons are resting those numbers.

I hope this is clear enough. Please, let me know if I need to explain it better. I'm usually able to figure out all my problems through a lot of internet searches. I just finally hit a wall.

```
private Button clearButton;
private Button drinkButton;
private Button shotButton;
private TextView textDrink;
private TextView textShot;
private int counterDrink = 0;
private int counterShot = 0;

public static final String DRINK_DATA = "DrinkData";
public static final String DEFAULT = "0";
SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    loadSavedPreferences();
}
...
private void loadSavedPreferences(){
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(DRINK_DATA, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String dataDrinkReturned = prefs.getString("DrinkData", DEFAULT);
    String dataShotReturned = prefs.getString("ShotData", DEFAULT);
    textDrink.setText(dataDrinkReturned);
    textShot.setText(dataShotReturned); }
```

'

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(DRINK_DATA, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String shotData = textShot.getText().toString();
    String drinkData = textDrink.getText().toString();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("DrinkData", drinkData);
    editor.putString("ShotData", shotData);
    editor.commit();
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to initialize the int-counters:

```
private void loadSavedPreferences(){
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(DRINK_DATA, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String dataDrinkReturned = prefs.getString("DrinkData", DEFAULT);
    String dataShotReturned = prefs.getString("ShotData", DEFAULT);
    counterDrink = Integer.parseInt(dataDrinkReturned);
    counterShot = Integer.parseInt(dataShotReturned );
    textDrink.setText(dataDrinkReturned);
    textShot.setText(dataShotReturned);
}
```

Although i feel it would be better than to save the int-values in the shared preferences instead of the string-values.

```
private void loadSavedPreferences(){
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(DRINK_DATA, MODE_PRIVATE);
    counterDrink  = prefs.getInt("DrinkData", 0);
    counterShot = prefs.getInt("ShotData", 0);
    textDrink.setText(""+counterDrink);
    textShot.setText(""+counterShot);
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(DRINK_DATA, MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor.putInt("DrinkData", counterDrink );
    editor.putInt("ShotData", counterShot );
    editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not setting the counter variables (`counterDrink` and `counterShot`) to the correct amount, and are always reset upon restarting the activity.

Instead of saving the counters to `SharedPreferences` as a `String`, I suggest saving it as an integer, and on top of setting the `TextView`s to the correct amount, you also need to set the `counterDrink` and `counterShot`.